# Creating Multiple Charts using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying to create multiple charts (i.e. different chart objects with one graph on each). I found a code on youtube that is linked in the comment that I'm modifying.

For now I want to be able to give `StartRow` which is a starting point and create a scatter plot of the next 700 rows. Then move to another column and plot that.

The code below does indeed create two chart objects but it is:

1. Creating multiple graphs on each chart object.
2. Selecting the data starting from Row 1 (instead of Row 5)
3. Selects x and y values for each graph in the same column.
4. The two chart objects are duplicates.

```
Sub AddCharts()


'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_p8hltGY4s

Dim StartRow as Integer
StartRow = 5

Dim j As Integer 'columns

For j = 5 To 7
    With Worksheets("CVData").Shapes.AddChart.Chart
   .ChartType = xlXYScatter
       
    '.ChartType = xlXYScatterPlot
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
       With .SeriesCollection(1)
       
        .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        Range(Cells(StartRow, 4), Cells(StartRow + 705, 4)).Address
        
        .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        Range(Cells(StartRow, j), Cells(StartRow + 700, j)).Address
        End With
    .HasLegend = False
  End With
Next j

End Sub
```

The data has this form and I want to create scatter plots of 700 entries of column D against E, K, H, and M:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this procedure with little modification and note that array of columns is made to loop through and values addresses are changed accordingly.

```
Sub AddCharts()
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437040/creating-multiple-charts-using-vba
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_p8hltGY4s
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim j As Long 'columns
Dim ColArr 'Columns array
StartRow = 5

ColArr = Array("E", "K", "H", "M")
For j = 0 To UBound(ColArr)
    With Worksheets("CVData").Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Chart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        Range(Cells(StartRow, 4), Cells(StartRow + 700, 4)).Address
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
        Range(Cells(StartRow, ColArr(j)), Cells(StartRow + 700, ColArr(j))).Address
    .HasLegend = False
    End With
Next j

End Sub
```

**EDIT as per comment below**
Check after replacing the with block above with the below. It takes series names from 4th row and removes extra series.

```
With Worksheets("CVData").Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "CVData!" & _
            Range(Cells(StartRow, 4), _
            Cells(StartRow + 700, 4)).Address & _
        "," & _
        "CVData!" & _
            Range(Cells(StartRow, ColArr(j)), _
            Cells(StartRow + 700, ColArr(j))).Address)
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=CVData!" & _
        Worksheets("CVData").Cells(StartRow - 1, ColArr(j)).Address
    .HasLegend = False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine but the series title is the entire column B. I can use `SeriesCollection(1).Name` to change it but there are still several series available  when I right click the chart and click 'Select Data'. Why is that? Secondly the vertical axis needs to be corrected which is not the case when I go through excel instead of vba. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I think `.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Cells(StartRow - 1, j).Value` shoul work .. I will check

Comment: Yes, after deleting all the extra series manually, the y-axis adjusts itself. So now the question is how to prevent those redundant series from being generated.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks a heap. I also found another solution. [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/adding-chart-with-vba-but-it-adds-too-many-series.940561/). It deletes all the unnecessary sheets.